# using spark scala ml model package in pyspark

Tags: python, scala, apache-spark, pyspark

Following package in spark has scala version of model to perform mixed effect models. There is no pyspark implementation of this package. Is there way to use a wrapper to run this package from pyspark

https://github.com/stitchfix/MomentMixedModels